# Failing to start IBM Http server with root user

Tags: apache, http, aix, ibmhttpserver

I had installed IBM Http server 8.5 on AIX(Not with root user). I'm able to start and stop the server with that user. Now my problem is, I had configured port 80 in httpd.conf file. But, as this is a port below 1024, I am trying to start the server with root user and I am getting the below error. Please help.

Error: ksh: apachectl:  not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a PATH problem:

```
#type apachectl 
apachectl is /usr/sbin/apachectl
```

Make sure that /usr/sbin is in your user path, or modify your start script to include full path